# Is $L^2_{\text{loc}}$ a Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis

My question is in the title. I know that $L^2$ is a Hilbert space, but I'm not sure about $L^2_{\text{loc}}$. Is it even an inner product space? Thanks.

Comment: It is a countably semi-normed topological vector space.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately $\mathbb L_{\mathrm{loc}}^2(\mathbb R)$ (and in general $\mathbb L_{\mathrm{loc}}^2(\Omega)$, where $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$, open) is not, and it can not become a Hilbert space, or an inner product space or even a normed space.

Its topology is determined by a countable family of semi-norms. Let $K_i\subset K_{i+1}\subset \Omega$, compact sets, such that $\cup_{i\in\mathbb N} K_i=\Omega$, and for every $f\in \mathbb L_{\mathrm{loc}}^2(\Omega)$ define
$$
p_i(f)=\left(\int_{K_i}|f|^2\,dx\right)^{1/2},
$$
then the $p_i$'s are semi-norms, and
$$
d(f,g)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{2^{-i}p_i(f-g)}{1+p_i(f-g)},
$$ 
defines a metric in $\mathbb L_{\mathrm{loc}}^2(\Omega)$, which makes $\mathbb L_{\mathrm{loc}}^2(\Omega)$ a [Fréchet space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_space).