# Is $L^2_\text{loc}$ a Hilbert space? How about $W^{k,2}_\text{loc}$

Tags: hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^k$. It is well-known that $L^2(\Omega)$ is a Hilbert space. But is the following local $L^2$-integrable function space
$$
L^2_\text{loc}(\Omega):=\{ f:\Omega\to \mathbb C \ \text{measurable} \mid  f\in L^2(K) \ \ \ \forall K \subset \subset \Omega \}
$$
still a Hilbert space? How about $W^{k,2}_\text{loc}(\Omega)$(defined in a similar way)?

More generally, what can we say about $W^{k,p}_\text{loc}(\Omega)$?

Comment: With respect to what inner product?

Comment: No, it is only a Fréchet space. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654597/is-l2-textloc-a-hilbert-space

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is $L^2_{\text{loc}}$ a Hilbert space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654597/is-l2-textloc-a-hilbert-space)